# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child . If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

i am not getting it can any one tell me whats my error.and also I am not getting it console in console errors(react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)

it's my app.js component

```
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Products from './Components/Products';
const App=()=> {
  const [products,setProducts]=useState([]);
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const response = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts((response && response.data) || []);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Products products={products} />}>
 
        </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

export default App;
```

its my index.js component

```
import React from 'react';

const Products=({products})=> {
    console.log('products===',products)
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product=>{
               return <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

its my commerce.js file

```
import Commerce from "@chec/commerce.js";
export const commerce=new Commerce(
    'pk_test_3545707b2e0c86f543293995b654f1d27dae48f368716',
    true
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the data you need to render the products page is being fetched and at that time is not available for your component to render so you kinda supplied null as a products param.

**What you can do**

1. Add a loading spinner or loading widget and in your routes file since that's where the products are being fetched do what's below.
2. Create a loading spinner component
3. `<Route path="/" element={products.length < 1 : <SpinnerComponent /> : <Products products={products} />}>`

This will show a loading spinner when the products array is empty and after a successful API call, it will show your products list

Comment: Is there any error in router component

Comment: sir not getting it

Comment: You are awaiting a response to render a component so you have to show a loading spinner and when the products state have been populated the products.length < 1 condition will be false and then render your Products component.

Answer (score 0):

You can console.log(products) to debug.

My assume is that your products didn't finish fetched before you rendering your route.

So you can go like

```
{ products ? products.map(product => {return <h1>{product.name}</h1>}) : ""}
```

Comment: not getting the result

Answer (score 0):

There is couple things that you have to do to resolve current and future problems.

1. use `products?.map(...)` instead of `products.map(...)`

   `?.` will call `map` when products is valid. (this will fails when `products` is an *Object* instead of an *Array*)
2. The other problem is that you call `setProducts` in an async function. but `setProducts` is an async function, too. So you have to add `await` before `setProducts`

   `await setProducts(...)`
3. And the last thing you have to do is checking `response.data` value.

   you will get an error message when `response.data` is an `Object` (as I mentioned before). to resolve this you have to first log the `response.data` to sure about its value type, and then use correct way to reach the data that you are looking for in response.